# Use macro code for only one specific column

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm still new to programming in excel and I am having trouble making slight changes to my code.My code enables the user to select a cell and then use the up and down arrows to choose a defined value. Looking at the code below, I call the functions "UpOne" and "DownOne" in my worksheet and then I have my saved strings values in a module.

Worksheet Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "UpOne"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "DownOne"
End Sub
```

Module Code

```
Sub DownOne()
    Select Case ActiveCell.Value
    Case ""
        ActiveCell.Value = "PASS"
    Case "PASS"
        ActiveCell.Value = "FAIL"
    Case "FAIL"
        ActiveCell.Value = "Unknown"
 End Sub
 Sub UpOne()
    Select Case ActiveCell.Value
    Case "Unknown"
        ActiveCell.Value = "FAIL"
    Case "FAIL"
        ActiveCell.Value = "PASS"
    Case "PASS"
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
 End Sub
```

My question is how would I make this code only work for all cells in one specific column? And how would I have different values when the user chooses a different column. So if user selects an empty cell in column "J", he/she can navigates with the arrows keys through values such as "A","B","C" but when he/she selects an empty cell in Column "N", he/she can navigate through a different set of values such as "E", "F", "G", etc.
thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than disabling/enabling code every time you selected a cell (plus you would need to cater for a multi-cell selection) it would be simpler for you to use Data Validation. You could set up lists that could apply to specific cells

Debra Dalgleish has an excellent discussion on Data Validation at [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval01.html)[image]

Comment: I see. The number of cells that use this data validation would be very big. This would not slow down the page load time too much?

Answer (score 1):

Rough code based on your original approach:

```
Sub DownOne()
   CycleValue Selection, -1
End Sub
Sub UpOne()
   CycleValue Selection, 1
End Sub

Sub CycleValue(rng As Range, GoDir As Integer)

    Dim arrA, arrB
    Dim arrVals, val
    Dim c As Range, m, indx As Integer
    Dim lb As Integer, ub As Integer
    Dim ProcessThis As Boolean

    arrA = Array("Fail", "Pass", "")
    arrB = Array("Eggs", "Bacon", "Toast", "Beans", "")

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        ProcessThis = True

        'what values are we cycling through?
        'based on column position
        If c.Column = 1 Then
            arrVals = arrA
        ElseIf c.Column = 5 Then
            arrVals = arrB
        Else
            ProcessThis = False 'not checking this column
        End If

        If ProcessThis Then
            lb = LBound(arrVals)
            ub = UBound(arrVals)
            val = Trim(c.Value)
            m = Application.Match(val, arrVals, 0)

            If IsError(m) Then
                indx = lb
            Else
                m = m - 1 '1-based
                indx = m + GoDir
                If indx < lb Then indx = ub
                If indx > ub Then indx = lb
            End If
            c.Value = arrVals(indx)
         End If
    Next c
End Sub
```